# Convert HTML to PDF using TCPDF

Tags: pdf-generation, tcpdf

I need to convert on the fly an HTML into PDF. I've been using the old HTMLDoc library for a while, but now I need to print SVG graphics and HTMLDoc doesn't support SVG nor base64-enconded images.
So far it seems to me that TCPDF (or a tool based on it) is a good way. The only problem is that I don't want to "build" the PDF document in PHP, as the HTML is dynamic.
Is there any way to write a script that simply takes a portion of HTML page and returns a PDF? That would imply some sort of way to specify start/stop markers in the HTML page (just like in HTMLDoc).

Thanks for any advice,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

TCPDF has got very limited css support and some bugs with " quotes, so from any html to pdf TCPDF is not an option for you unfortunetly

Answer (score 0):

TCPDF not supports all css functionality, **mpdf** 6.0 is best ever pdf library for convert html to pdf, It also supports almost required css as well. I prefers htmlcanvas jquery for convert html to image.